# Write to_csv with Python Pandas: Choose which column index to insert new data

Tags: python, parsing, csv, pandas

I have a set of data output in my program that I want to write to a .csv file. I am able to make a new file with the old input data, followed by the new data in the last column to the right. How can I manipulate which column my output data goes to? Also, how can I choose to not include the old input data in my new file? I'm new to pandas.

Thanks!

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html There is a method to do this using your pandas dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading from file:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('D:\\Apps\\Coursera\\Kaggle-Titanic\\Data\\train.csv', header = 0)
```

Some manipulation:

```
df['Gender'] = df.Sex.map(lambda x: 0 if x=='female' else 1)
df['FamilySize'] = df.SibSp + df.Parch
```

Copy some fields to new:

```
result = df[['Sex', 'Survived', 'Age']]
```

Delete not needed fields:

```
del result['Sex']
```

Save to the file:

```
result.to_csv('D:\\Apps\\Coursera\\Kaggle-Titanic\\Swm\\result.csv', index=False)
```

Or if you want to save only some fields or in some specific order:

```
df[['Sex', 'Survived', 'Age']].to_csv('D:\\Apps\\Coursera\\Kaggle-Titanic\\Swm\\result.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for the complete overview of how to manipulate data in .csv files! This should serve my purpose perfectly.